# Bluetooth enable request is not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

On my Android set, it's prompting that the activity has unfortunately stopped.

Comment: I do not think this is the issue.  Your activity stopped because of a different issue in the code.  Show more code and more detailed error/exception description.

Comment: post your logcat stacktrace

Comment: Have you added permission for bluetooth in manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Bluetooth permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```